# JasperReports compilation using wrong temp directory when trying to use lateset jars abovev 4.5.1 to support java 1.8

Tags: java, jasper-reports, java-8

I'm using the JasperReports library version 4.5.1 in my Java application, and I'm trying to upgrade higher versions to upgrade to java 1.8.

I am using the JasperReports ant task to build our *.jrxml files into *.jasper files at compile time. Here is the relevant excerpt from our build.xml file:

```
<target name="compile-report" depends="init">
    <taskdef name="jrc" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask" classpath="${javac.classpath}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.classes.dir}/usda/weru/weps/reports"/>
    <jrc tempdir="${build.classes.dir}/usda/weru/weps/reports" compiler="usda.weru.weps.reports.compile.JRJavacCompiler" destdir="${build.classes.dir}/usda/weru/weps/reports">
        <src>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/reports">
                <include name="**/*.jrxml"/>                    
            </fileset>
        </src>
        <classpath path="${run.classpath}"/>
    </jrc>
    <!--copy the styles into the classpath-->
    <copy todir="${build.classes.dir}/usda/weru/weps/reports">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/reports">
            <include name="**/*.jrtx"/>
        </fileset>            
    </copy>
</target>
```

I could not figure why JasperReports trying to save anything in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0\? I specify a temp directory in the ant task, why does it not use that location?

Here is the full text of the exception stack trace:

```
File : C:\Users\maxerdwien\Documents\Netbeans_src\baseline\weps.gui-max\reports\_harvestsdetail.jrxml ... FAILED.
Error compiling report design : C:\Users\maxerdwien\Documents\Netbeans_src\baseline\weps.gui-max\reports\_harvestsdetail.jrxml
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error saving expressions class file : C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0\_harvestsdetail_1417022482708_967062.java
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRSaver.saveClassSource(JRSaver.java:153)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.getSourceFile(JRAbstractCompiler.java:310)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.createCompileUnit(JRAbstractCompiler.java:282)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:177)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:240)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:496)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:156)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:445)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:138)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask.compile(JRAntCompileTask.java:402)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask.execute(JRAntCompileTask.java:249)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor222.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor222.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0\_harvestsdetail_1417022482708_967062.java (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRSaver.saveClassSource(JRSaver.java:145)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: Your error logs state that `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0\_harvestsdetail_1417022482708_967062.java (Access is denied)` Are you sure that you have access to the given file and folders?

Comment: The problem is that i gave a temp folder to write the class files but is picking up the NetBeasns directory . This problem i faced if i upgrade the Jasper reports jar from 4.5.1 to higher.